# C# - Não mostrar formulário sendo montado para o usuário

Tags: c#, winforms

Olá.

No VBA do excel tem um recurso muito legal.

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Isso impede de mostrar a tela sendo montada para o usuário e mostrar somente depois de tudo carregado.

Queria uma coisa assim no C#. Tenho alguns formulários com muitos controles e é um pouco demorado seu carregamento. Ele fica mostrando a montagem de cada componente.

Será que tem como fazer isso? Colocar um panel mostrando "Loading..." enquanto o formulário está sendo montando e depois habilitar sua visualização?

Desde já, agradeço a quem puder ajudar nisso.

Att.

Comment: Então jovem, se teu fomulário é tão lento assim deve ter alguma coisa errada nele não? Lendo sua explicação, enquanto ocorre uma ação, outra teria de ser executada... pensei no Background Worker (http://www.macoratti.net/13/07/c_backg1.htm) conhece? Chega perto do que você precisa?

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o porque da demora. Eu tinha colocado o carregamento do banco e os demais modificadores no bloco "InitializeComponent();" que é o construtor do formulário. Então abri o evento form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e), que é o bloco que é executado após o formulário ser carregado, e coloquei todo o código do modificador lá e também a consulta do banco. Que diferença! Agora sim ficou rápido.